# How to pass string to shell script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

My task is to connect my python code with the C++ code (called `streamer`) and then get the result back to python script. I have to send two parameters to the C++ code. The first one is just integer (no problem here), but the second one is a long string that you can see here.

```
8 0
37 0
81 0
95 0
116 0
133 0
145 0
184 0
207 0
223 0
258 0
277 0
```

In the C++ code, I am just printing both arguments using this code to see what I passed:

```
std::cout << "ARGUMENT 1: " << argv[1] <<'\n';
std::cout << "ARGUMENT 2: " << argv[2] <<'\n';
```

I tried several approaches that I've found here, but nothing works. When I try this python code it doesn't treat the second argument (long string) as one string but as multiple arguments.

```
p = subprocess.Popen([r'./Solver/solver.sh', str(3), long_string], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
solver_result, err = p.communicate()

print(solver_result)
print(err)
```

Another approach that I've tried is here. This time it just prints the first argument and that it crashes with error code `139` which is most likely because there is no `argv[2]`

```
p = subprocess.run([r'./Solver/solver.sh', str(3)], stdout=PIPE, input=long_string, encoding='ascii')
print(p.returncode)
print(p.stdout)
```

Shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./Solver/streamer $1 $2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `long_string`?

Comment: Note that your script needs to *quote* its arguments to ensure they're passed through correctly. `./Solver/streamer "$1" "$2"`, or better, `./Solver/streamer "$@"` to just pass them all through. Without the quotes, an empty string will disappear and not generate any arguments at all; a `*` will generate one argument per file in your current directory; `two words` will become one argument per word (with a default IFS), etc.

Comment: BTW, if you ran your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking here, it would have linked you to [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in your shell script, not in your Python.

Quote your arguments to prevent them from being word-split, and then having each word separately processed as a glob:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./Solver/streamer "$1" "$2"
```